# Mobile Filter Dropdown Menu

Tags: drop-down-list, sort, filter

I have a **web application** that has been **responsively designed for mobile**. While in a parent container you can apply filters to sort children. I am debating between two design types.

Option A:

This is a typical dropdown menu overlaying on top of child elements

[image]

Option B:

This is a native style option when the menu comes up from the bottom and an overlay over the children focuses the users attention on the menu items.

[image]

Arguably option A follows traditional browser paradigms while option b follows more native mobile UX. It has been 50/50 on the which way to go, is there a specific way I should look at this while building a browser web application?

Answer (score 1):

Luke Wroblewski takes this a step further and claims that on mobile, "[Dropdowns should be the UI of last resort](https://storify.com/lukew/drop-downs-are-the-ui-of-last-resort)", citing factors such as:

- Number of taps required
- Impact on the look and feel
- Visual and cognitive noise
- Perceived ease of use

Note that he does not talk about "desktop-model dropdown vs. mobile-model dropdown". He says that even the mobile-model dropdown should be ditched in favor of more appropriate controls, where possible (in some cases in may not be possible).

Comment: That is a very interesting article thanks for the link. However in this situation due to the amount of content of the page I do not think it is possible to have anything except a dropdown. Even if I could change it I dont think I am allowed, so in this case it really comes down to the 2 options